# Intent not working in NavigationDrawerFragment

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to call another activity using my NavigationDrawerFragment. Under my onOptionsItemSelected I create an intent and call the said intent but for some reason it is showing up as an error.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
```

I was wondering why it was not working since :

- I already have a HomeActivity class
- I also have added it in the manifest
- Other activities are also calling the HomeActivity class and it seems to be working just fine.

  @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
              return true;
          }

  ```
      if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
          Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                  .show();


         int pos = 1;
         switch(pos){

         case 1:
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
              this.startActivity(intent);
              break;  

         }

          return true;
      }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  ```

Am I doing something wrong in my code which is why it is showing up as an error?
Update:

The error message is this:

> The constructor Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment, Class)
>   is undefined

Comment: What error do you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code snippet is from a `Fragment` then you should use `new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class);`.

The same applies to the following line, by the way.